# Telling a TxId from a contract to use it in a webapp?

Tags: txid, tx, webapp

I want to submit a transaction and then expose that `TxId` to the PAB via the contracts `tell` function.
This `TxId` can then be used by a front end as a more precise pointer to the onchain representation of some Utxo(with a little bit of drilling).

Is this a viable method of tethering onchain Utxo’s to a web apps interface?

In order for this to work, `TxId` has to be decoded into a `Tx`…and I’m not sure if there is a function for that.

The other option is to not tell any state from the contract and just drill into the Utxos at the script address.
This method was shown numerous times in the PPP, but it runs into problems when there are multiple Utxos at the script address locked by the same pk.